# Determinate the collection and remove one specific item in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Starting from this example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in collectionA track by item.instanceid">
    <input id="{{item.instanceid}}" style="display:none">
    <input ng-model="item.name" type="text">
    <button onclick="Remove({{item.instanceid}})">Remove</button>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in collectionB track by item.instanceid">
    <input value="{{item.instanceid}}" style="display:none">
    <input ng-model="item.name" type="text">
    <button onclick="Remove({{item.instanceid}})">Remove</button>
</div>

<script>
    function Remove(instanceid){
        var container = $('#'+instanceid).closest('div');   
        var scopeItem = angular.element(container).scope();
        ....
    }
</script>
```

This is a simplification of my use case, but I need to remain with this kind of code structure. So, starting from this point I want to know if in `Remove` function is possible to remove from collectionA or collectionB an object knowing only its `instanceid` (which is a unique identifier by definition).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mixing angular with vanilla JS ways of doing things, why not use the full power of angular?

Specifically, I am referring to using `ng-click` instead of `onclick`:

`<button ng-click="Remove($index, 'collectionA')">Remove</button>`

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.Remove = function(index, collection) {
    $scope[collection].splice(index, 1);
};
```

Using the `$index` from ng-repeat removes the need to search the array based on the instanceid.

**EDIT**: OP claims he needs a way to remove array items using the `intanceid`, I'll go ahead and show how although I am unsure of how he is determining which collection to search:

```
$scope.Remove = function(instanceid) {
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.collection.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ($scope.collection[i].instanceid === instanceid) {
            $scope.collection.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that buttons are added dynamically with javascript and when i create them i couldn't know the collection name. I need to know if exist a way to do what I need using only my instanceid.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The buttons are being created in your ng-repeat, are they not? You have defined which collection in `<div ng-repeat="item in collectionA track by item.instanceid">`. Am I missing something? There is a way to use the instanceid and I'll go ahead and update my answer with it, but I'm unsure why you need it.

Comment: No it's correct what you say, and buttons are not created in ng-repeat but are added with javascript after the page was renderer. So it's all correct and what i need to understand is if exists a way to know the collection cycled by ng-repeat from Remove function.